# Button not being displayed when using pack()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, grid, pack

I am trying to create a GUI application (just starting), but I have run into a problem.

When i use .pack() (which i need to use) the button is not getting displayed, but if i use .grid(), it does display.

This is the code:

```
class TemperaturePlotApp(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.master.title("Max Temperature")
        self.button = Button(self, text="Browse", command=self.load_file,
                             width=10, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

    def load_file(self):
        fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Text File", "*.txt")))
        if fname:
            try:
                print("""here it comes: self.settings["template"].set(fname)""")
            except:                     # <- naked except is a bad idea
                showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read file\n'%s'" % fname)

            return

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = TemperaturePlotApp(root)
    root.geometry("800x400")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If i use .grid(), it works:

```
self.master.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
self.master.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
self.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S)

self.button = Button(self, text="Browse", command=self.load_file, width=10)
self.button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
```

I have to use .pack(), not grid, so if someone could please explain what i am doing wrong, i would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks
Corey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are not *packing* your `TemperaturePlotApp` widget (which derives from a `Frame`). Try the following code:

```
...
app = TemperaturePlotApp(root)
app.pack()
...
```

Notice also that you are probably importing tkinter in the following way:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

Because you are inheriting from a `Frame` widget using:

```
class TemperaturePlotApp(tk.Frame):
```

On the other hand, you are trying to create a button using:

```
self.button = Button(...)
```

Which means that either you are using another button from another library (for example `ttk`) or you are having conflicts or something similar. You might want it like:

```
self.button = tk.Button(...)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks heaps for that. It is much appreciated. The problem is that I am not allowed to change the code in or below the main() method, as I am doing this for university. They also insist i use .pack rather than .grid. Do you know of any way around this? Thanks :)

Comment: @Fishingfon You can then pack your widget directly in the contructor (`__init__` method) as last statement. For example: `self.pack()`.

Comment: That was perfect! Thanks heaps :)

Comment: @Fishingfon Notice that `*args` and `**kwargs` are usually not passed to a spefic field (you are passing them to the Button), but to the contructor of the super class, in your case the super class is `Frame`, so you should pass those arguments to the super constructor: `tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)`. This is not a rule, but...actually it depends on what you want to achieve...